# What's the difference between Password and Personal Password, as well as username ad Nickname, in IRC?

Tags: irc

I signed up in freenode IRC by registering a Nickname.

Now in the Textual IRC client, I see these different options:

Nickname, Username, and Personal Password:

[image: Nickname vs Username]

and Password:

[image: Password]

What's the difference between Username and Nickname? Does Freenode support both? And what's the Password field in the second screenshot for?

Comment: See also: https://www.reddit.com/r/irc/comments/2qyg0u/difference_between_username_and_nickname/

Answer (score 3):

`Nickname` - This is your public ID, and what people will see when you talk in an IRC channel.

`Username` - This identifies your connection, and is displayed during connection and disconnection messages. For example: `Nickname has disconnected. (Username@ISP.etc.com)`.

`Personal Password` - This is used to auto-identify with NickServ or as you can see SASL. Nickserv is designed to let you register and reserve a Nickname with a specific server. Or in the case of SASL, allow you to identify yourself to Nickserv (or other services) as the first step in connecting to the network, before anything else happens.

`Password` - This field is only necessary if there is a password required to connect to the IRC Server.

- http://freenode.net/sasl/
- http://freenode.net/faq.shtml#userregistration